# VSCode Extension: How to open a file if no workspace folders are available?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've been working on an extension that allows adding files with pre-defined content and modifying them using a custom web editor.
The custom command "Add new XXX file" looks like the following:

```
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('myextension.add-new-file', () => {
    if(vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders?.length){
        const rootPath = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.fsPath ;
        let counter = 0;
        let filePath = '';
        do{
            counter++;
            filePath = path.join(rootPath, `NewFile${counter}.my-ext`);
        }while(fs.existsSync(filePath));
        fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(newFileContent), 'utf8');
        const openPath = vscode.Uri.file(filePath); 
        vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.openWith', openPath, 'myextension.custom-designer');                 
    }
});
```

It works OK if a folder is opened in VS Code. However, if no folder is opened, the rootPath can't be resolved. What's the solution for such a scenario? Does the 'vscode.openWith' accept the file content instead of the path to open?

Comment: create an untitled document and fill it with text

Comment: @rioV8 how could I open the untitled document with my custom editor?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your goal using the `untitled` scheme:

```js
vscode.commands.executeCommand(
  'vscode.openWith',
  vscode.Uri.parse("untitled:FooBar"),
  'myextension.custom-designer',
);
```

You can change your custom editor so that it detects when empty document gets passed to it and replaces the empty document with `newFileContent`.